# need assisstance to set python2.7 as default & Django to install

Tags: linux, django, python-2.7, centos

I am not able to install Django.I am using CentOS 5,not able to set python2.7 environment variable.Priviously in my system python2.4.3 is available,but after installing python 2.7 in the terminal i checked the version avail in system using "python -V"cmd it executed as python 2.4.3.But if i checked using "python2.7 -V"cmd it is showing python2.7.Please help me with this.....

1.I need to set python2.7 as default version.

2.Help me with the installation of Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CentOS relies on python 2.4 so that's not going to work. You should probably create a new system user and install pyton 2.7 in its home directory (or use your root user and install python in /opt for global usage), you can find plenty of tutorials on Google.

After succesfully doing so, you can set an alias in your user's bash profile to define which python version to use. It's also common practice to create a virtualenv for each project and/or user.